# Scala does not Compile when clicking Run IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compilation

Using InteliJ I have to hit Compile before I do Run otherwise the current code edits do not execute.

How can I make it so scala files are compiled automatically so all I have to do is press Run like with Java?

It might be important to note I am using scala files in a java project.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a macro to Save and Compile mapped to `CMD+s`

I would like a better solution. As such, I am willing to wait for an answer before accepting my own.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Run Configuration and add the "Make" step to it.

[image]

Comment: I always set to Make, No Error Check.  For Dev.